# Getting all file versions in document library SharePoint 2010

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-enterprise

Is there a way to get all the file names with paths along side their version counts in sharepoint document library

Answer (score 1):

These posts can help you with your effort (some tweaking to include the properties of path & count will be needed to the scripts below) -

- [Powershell: Update all Document Libraries with MajorVersionLimit and MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit](http://www.mysticslayer.com/?p=171)
- [PowerShell Script to Delete All Versions in a Document Library](http://www.mukalian.com/blog/post/2011/04/10/PowerShell-Script-to-Delete-All-Versions-in-a-Document-Library.aspx)